# consulta en oracle sql y traer esa columna virtual en un ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Estoy haciendo una consulta en oracle sql y al hacer un substr a una columna

```
(columna,0,4) as colum
```

como puedo traer esa columna en un `ResultSet`

```
(miResultset.getString("colum"));
```

ya intente asi y regresa vacio incluso cambie por el `getInt` y cambie por `1` en lugar de `colum` y siempre vuelve vacio ese dato

Comment: y de que tipo es esa columna en tu base de datos? varchar2(64)?

Comment: Un string en Oracle comienza con la posición 1. Pero, bueno, Oracle corrige tu error y convierte la 0 a una 1 internamente. ¿Es solamente el substr que no funciona? ¿Otras campos recibes? ¿Es que ejecutas la consulta, compruebas si hay errores, y no los hay, lees las filas, y eso funciona, pero el campo de la(s) fila(s) es vacío? Por favor muestra mas código.

Comment: asi es regresan bien las otras columnas solo las virtuales que creo cuando hago el as colum es la qeu vuelve vacia siempre

Comment: adjunto estoy haciendo esto
 caja.cajas.set(miResultset.getString(colum));
luego imprimo System.out.println("caja es  " + caja.cajas);
e imprime vacio el error esta en el set osea no mueve el valor del result lo curioso es que en las demas columnas si lo mueve y lo imprime sin problemas

Comment: Lo siento, no sé. Es que no uso ni jdbc ni java. De todos modos tienes que editar tu pregunta y mostrar el parte del programa en lo que sacas los datos y los muestras. Como diez a treinta lineas del código quizás, para que podemos ver que pasa exactamente.